# How to verify a customer has made payment using fake paypal or verified paypal account?

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn, paypal-sandbox

I have integrated my shopping cart with paypal for physical shipment product. System required verified paypal user.

How to verify a customer has made payment using fake paypal or verified paypal account?

Comment: what you mean by  `fake paypal`

Comment: a paypal account that has not confirmed a bank account or card

Comment: @ZakirHossain who cares, as long as the PAYMENT is CONFIRMED..

Comment: If the documented Paypal IPN verification process has succeeded, it is a genuine transaction and the funds are in your account. The IPN contains a field that tells you whether the user is verified. Hard to see why they would transfer the funds if he wasn't.

Comment: @hanshenrik freelancer.com, upwork.com .....

Comment: @EJP IPN verification process just check the payment has made or not but not verified that the user has added bank account or card

Comment: *As I also said,* the IPN contains this information. It is the `payer_status` field and it is set to `verified` in this case, or `unverified` in the other. See [Payment Information Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB04C0HS/).

Answer (score 0):

The only API available is [GetVerifiedStatus](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/api/adaptive-accounts/GetVerifiedStatus_API_Operation/)

The GetVerifiedStatus API operation lets you determine whether the specified PayPal account's status is verified or unverified.

A PayPal account achieves verified status under a variety of circumstances, such as when an account is linked to a verified funding source. Verified status indicates a trust relationship.

or use [IPN](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/products/instant-payment-notification/)

Answer (score 0):

The IPN itself contains this information. It is the `payer_status` field and it is set to `verified` in this case, or `unverified` in the other. See [Payment Information Variables](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNandPDTVariables/#id091EB04C0HS/). Provided you've done IPN validation and it has succeeded, that's all you need.

Comment: I belive he is refering to a OnBoarding process - https://developer.paypal.com/docs/multiparty/seller-onboarding/before-payment/